# Storing assets in Apigee

Tags: javascript, node.js, apigee

I am trying to upload assets to apigee baas for which I follow the docu in here:
http://apigee.com/docs/api-baas/content/assets

Here is my code:

```
    var querystring = require('querystring');

    var data = querystring.stringify({
        filename: 'car_123.jpg', //asset's name on Apigee
        file_location: 'http://cdn.xxxx.com/cars/123.jpg' //asset's original destination
    });

    var target_url = "https://api.usergrid.com/<org>/<app>/cars/<uuid>?access_token=dummyaccesstokenfor_SO"

    var options = {
        method: 'POST',
        url: target_url,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(data)
        }
    };

    var request = require('request');

    request(options, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err)
        } else {
            console.log('success')    
        };
    });
```

When I run this, I get a success message. I want to believe that the image from the cdn is physically
copied into Apigee. Seems that's not true

because, when I issue a GET on 
    https://api.usergrid.com/org/app/cars/uuid?access_token=dummyaccesstokenfor_SO with header 'Accept:image/jpeg', all I get is this

> filename=cars_123.jpg&file_location='http://cdn.xxxx.com/cars/123.jpg

And no base64 image string or image url.

Where am I going wrong?

EDIT: I don't see anything in the BaaS GUI either

EDIT2: As per remus's suggestion

> curl -X POST -i -F name='apple-128' -F file=@"https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/flat-brand-logo-2/512/apple-128.png" 'http://requestb.in/11xu3h61'

this results in

> curl: (26) couldn't open file "https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/flat-brand-logo-2/512/apple-128.png"

The cdn used here is just a place holder. But the result with my cdn is just the same. So, it is failing even before the POST. Makes me wonder if the file location can be a http location at all or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The endpoint you call should look like `/{org}/{app}/{collection}/{entity uuid}` with the Accept: image/jpg header. Also if you look in the BaaS GUI, you should see the entity there with the file details and content length.

Since it's still not working, here's a CURL command that will properly upload the asset:

```bash
curl -X POST -i -F name='image' -F file=@"/path/to/image.jpg" 'https://api.usergrid.com/{org}/{app}/{collection}/{uuid}'
```

You could try POSTing both this CURL and your Node method against [requestbin](http://requestb.in/) and compare the results?

Comment: I suppose the GET url was formatted by SO. It does read the same nomenclature as suggested by you.

And I don't see anything in the BaaS GUI

Comment: Hmm is there an entity at all? Or is the collection empty?

Comment: There is. The collection CARS is full of car entities. And now I am trying to add images to them

Comment: Tried it - but it's throwing up a different error all together. Please check EDIT2

Comment: Ahh, I see. I think it's not working because it hasn't downloaded the file. Try doing a request.pipe()?

Comment: You mean in node? How do I do that? Will try

Comment: Using the request module - you'd do something like request.get(~URL~).pipe(function(data) {... Return your post code ...});